# Is this a common shape of graph in Thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, ising-model

I am calculating the acceptance ratios of the local and non-local Kawasaki algorithm for the Ising model and generated the following graph:

[image: acceptance]

This shape of graph comes over as kind of familiar, is this a common shape of graph in thermodynamics? I was thinking in terms of a certain phase transition.

Comment: Does it asymptotically reach a value at infinite temperature? If so, it looks like an entropy vs. temperature curve to me

Comment: It does asymptotically reach $1$